# {} in linq result

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var query = from c in customers
                join o in orders on c.ID equals o.ID
                select new { c.ID, c.City, SalesBefore = c.Sales, NewOrder = o.Amount, SalesAfter = c.Sales + o.Amount };

    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

I was running above code in console application. When it generates the result, it is displayed in the `{}`. Why is the result in the `{}`?

Example result

```
{ ID=1, City=New York.....}
```

There is nothing crucial. Just curious to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's just the default `.ToString` implementation of anonymous types.  Nothing more or less.

Answer (score 2):

That code uses the `Console.WriteLine(object)` overload, which under the hood calls the `.ToString()` method on the object given. The `.ToString()` method, in turn, renders an anonymous type in that way.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the look they've chosen when overriding the `ToString` method. It does mean that the object looks like a property bag, which is basically what it is.